# ngx-bootstrap 6.1.0 with Angular 10 Popover is not working

Tags: angular, popover, ngx-bootstrap, angular10

I migrated from **Angular 9** to **10** and also from the version of **ngx-bootstrap 5.5.0** to **6.1.0** and Popovers doesn't appear.

I already have in the app.module and shared.module the import for the `PopoverModule.forRoot()`.

Is there an issue reported about popovers for version **6.1.0** of **ngx-bootstrap**?

Example of the code:

TS

```
import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PopoverModule.forRoot(),
]
})
export class ProjectAngularModule { }
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary"
  popover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
  [popoverTitle]="'Popover on ' + placement"
  [placement]="placement">
  {{ 'Popover on ' + placement }} 
</button>
```

Comment: share your minimal code check [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover)

Comment: i have everything with the correct settings, but this isn't work

Comment: Well obviously you don't as the link @KiranMistry provides such an example that works, in order to help more information is needed as trivial things might be missed